# Print 2 common maximum values of a python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have imported a csv to pandas' data frame.

```
                         Work Product  Version
0  LCR_ContractualOutflowsMaster.aspx      1.1
1              LCR_CountryMaster.aspx      1.1
2          WBR_LCR_ContOutflowsMaster      1.0
3           USP_WBR_LCR_CountryMaster      1.0
```

Then then data frame was inserted in to a python dictionary.

```
{'LCR_ContractualOutflowsMaster.aspx': [1.1], 'LCR_CountryMaster.aspx': [1.1], 'WBR_LCR_ContOutflowsMaster': [1.0], 'USP_WBR_LCR_CountryMaster': [1.0]}
```

There are two keys which have common maximum value `1.1`. **Is there a way to print out these two keys into a list?**

I have tried some methods such as (referred from some stack overflow queries)

```
1) max_value = max(csv_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

2) max_value = max(csv_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

3) max_value = max(csv_dict.values()); {key for key, value in csv_dict.items() if value == max_value}

4) max_value = max(csv_dict, key=csv_dict.get)
```

It is only printing one value.

Regards

Comment: Why not use the DataFrame? `df.loc[df.Version == df.Version.max(), 'Work Product'].tolist()`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588298/pandas-idxmax-return-all-rows-in-case-of-ties?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to do this in pandas directly, but rather insist on using a dict?

Comment: @user3483203 I am getting AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'loc'. My pandas version is 0.25.0.

Comment: after you have computed `max_value`, use list comprehensions: `keys = [k for (k,v) in csv_dict.items() if v == max_value]`. It should work. I'd compute `max_value` using your 2nd option: `max_value = max(csv_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]`. You cannot both find the max value and filter the entries in one iteration. It will have to be two separate iterations, still O(n) in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `df['Version']==df['Version'].max()` this actually fetch all records which contains maximum value of version.As you can see by dataframe 2 is a maximum value so the first two records would be fetched due to first line of code.

2- `df['Work Product'].unique()` this fetch unique work_product against maximum value of version

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Work Product":["A","B","C","D"],
                       "Version":[2,2,1,1]})

df = df[df['Version'] ==df['Version'].max()]
uq_work_product = list(df['Work Product'].unique())
print(uq_work_product)
```

```
['A', 'B']
```

Comment: It has worked! But also explain what is happening behind the scenes in these two lines -------------------> df = df[df['Version'] ==df['Version'].max()] and 
uq_work_product = list(df['Work Product'].unique())? It will help readers like me who are new to pandas

Comment: Got it mate! Good Explanation

Comment: @KrisT great :)